# How to start 2 services at different ports using jmdns?

Tags: android, airplay, jmdns

I need to start 2 services simultaneously (i.e airplay and airtunes) using jmdns. I'm able to start one service using jmdns but when I register 2 services simultaneously it gives me exception while sending data from IOS.

Here is my code:

```
void startDNSService() {

    final JmDNS jmDNS = JmDNS.create(address); /* Create mDNS responder for address */
    s_jmDNSInstances.add(jmDNS);
    jmDNS.registerServiceType(AIR_TUNES_SERVICE_TYPE); /* Initialization service name */

    String name = Utils.servName.length() > 0 ? Utils.servName : Utils.HardwareAddressString + "@X" + android.os.Build.MODEL;
    Utils.servName = name;
    /* Publish RAOP service */
    final ServiceInfo airPlayServiceInfo = ServiceInfo.create(
                                                              AirPlayConstant.type,name, /* Service Name */
                                                              AirPlayConstant.port, 0 /* weight */, 0 /* priority */,
                                                              AirPlayConstant.getTxtHead());
    jmDNS.registerService(airPlayServiceInfo);

    final JmDNS     jmDNS = JmDNS.create(InetAddress.getByName(ip),"audio");//AirTunes Service Strart code:

    jmDNSInstances.add(jmDNS);//   Create mDNS responder for address
    jmDNS.registerServiceType(AirPlayConstant.type);
    //   Publish RAOP service
    final ServiceInfo airTunesServiceInfo = ServiceInfo.create(AIR_TUNES_SERVICE_TYPE, "Airplay", getRtspPort(), 0 , 0 ,
                                                               AIRTUNES_SERVICE_PROPERTIES);

    jmDNS.registerService(airTunesServiceInfo);

}
```

I've got `ChannelCloseException` while sharing audio from iTunes through AirTunes service. Video works well.

Comment: I guess you are not sending proper reply to a request from iOS device. When you start Airplay and Airtunes services on a device (your android server) and after connecting to try to share audio from iOS device (your client), iOS device sends POST/fp-setup request to your Android requesting a fair-play setup of rtsp stream. Did you break POST/fp-setup request from iOS ?? Let me know if you require help to break it...

Comment: @Tahir yes, that did the trick. Can you post that as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we are running ONLY Airtunes service on Android and share audio from iOS, on Android we recieve something like:

```
DefaultHttpRequest(chunked: false)
OPTIONS * RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 0
X-Apple-Device-ID: 0xf4f95172ac4a
Apple-Challenge: Vil4gZ2Sihm72isehrFb2g==
DACP-ID: 9A4EC4744A1C604D
Active-Remote: 1509410937
User-Agent: AirPlay/200.54
```

and your Android needs to send following response to iOS device:

```
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
Public: ANNOUNCE, SETUP, RECORD, PAUSE, FLUSH, TEARDOWN, OPTIONS, GET_PARAMETER, SET_PARAMETER
CSeq: 0
Audio-Jack-Status: connected; type=analog
Apple-Response: CXMubVPs0Dy3IsHCNrOLTJbaVLhhL8eXX8+ctx2fJ62BeKm90HCYn1H0iYeBW52SKDtC97LI2JOK5U8kArfcDJX58F4+9iEAoFNrGBEcveN0PVCrZTmyUX1m5ldNnJYjAArdr8QJb9TrkMHpItP4lbv13DgWnv9qYRsAXA5okLpnbiCmeTiA3or3abK0OiVShjFlhcYetb8VfolCs6+907pRKQsJV4FS4XXY2c/wwlGQAh1ifru/QALxFKye7akiaegVnMH/+k68drFWNlUVPBJua20yc/LAT9Hbhz4yEBvehgh/CoBRYaOHu3VxwIjIlKRkqwobONk7hA687ASp7A==
```

BUT When you start Airplay and Airtunes services on a device (your android server) and when you try to share audio from iOS device, iOS device sends POST/fp-setup request to your Android requesting a fair-play setup of rtsp stream as follows:

```
POST /fp-setup RTSP/1.0
X-Apple-ET: 32
CSeq: 0
X-Apple-Device-ID: 0xf4f95172ac4a
DACP-ID: 9A4EC4744A1C604D
Active-Remote: 1853152273
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 16
User-Agent: AirPlay/200.54
contents:
[F, P, L, Y, , , , ,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

you need to send its response back to iOS device. This is a kind of challenge.

In your RaopAudioHandler.java send response to `POST /fp-setup RTSP/1.0` as below:

```
@Override
public void messageReceived(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final MessageEvent evt) throws Exception {
    final HttpRequest req = (HttpRequest) evt.getMessage();
    final HttpMethod method = req.getMethod();

    LogManager.w("messageReceived : HttpMethod: " + method);


    if (method.toString().equals("POST") && req.getUri().equals("/fp-setup")) {

        // 2 1 1 -> 4 : 02 00 02 bb
        byte fply_1[] = {
            0x46, 0x50, 0x4c, 0x59, 0x02, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x02, 0x00, 0x02, (byte) 0xbb
        };

        // 2 1 2 -> 130 : 02 02 xxx
        byte fply_2[] = {
            0x46, 0x50, 0x4c, 0x59, 0x02, 0x01, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, (byte) 0x82, 0x02, 0x02, 0x2f, 0x7b, 0x69, (byte) 0xe6, (byte) 0xb2, 0x7e, (byte) 0xbb, (byte) 0xf0, 0x68, 0x5f, (byte) 0x98, 0x54, 0x7f, 0x37, (byte) 0xce, (byte) 0xcf, (byte) 0x87, 0x06, (byte) 0x99, 0x6e, 0x7e, 0x6b, 0x0f, (byte) 0xb2, (byte) 0xfa, 0x71, 0x20, 0x53, (byte) 0xe3, (byte) 0x94, (byte) 0x83, (byte) 0xda, 0x22, (byte) 0xc7, (byte) 0x83, (byte) 0xa0, 0x72, 0x40, 0x4d, (byte) 0xdd, 0x41, (byte) 0xaa, 0x3d, 0x4c, 0x6e, 0x30, 0x22, 0x55, (byte) 0xaa, (byte) 0xa2, (byte) 0xda, 0x1e, (byte) 0xb4, 0x77, (byte) 0x83, (byte) 0x8c, 0x79, (byte) 0xd5, 0x65, 0x17, (byte) 0xc3, (byte) 0xfa, 0x01, 0x54, 0x33, (byte) 0x9e, (byte) 0xe3, (byte) 0x82, (byte) 0x9f, 0x30, (byte) 0xf0, (byte) 0xa4, (byte) 0x8f, 0x76, (byte) 0xdf, 0x77, 0x11, 0x7e, 0x56, (byte)(byte) 0x9e, (byte)(byte) 0xf3, (byte) 0x95, (byte) 0xe8, (byte) 0xe2, (byte) 0x13, (byte) 0xb3, (byte) 0x1e, (byte) 0xb6, (byte) 0x70, (byte) 0xec, (byte) 0x5a, (byte) 0x8a, (byte) 0xf2, (byte) 0x6a, (byte) 0xfc, (byte) 0xbc, (byte) 0x89, (byte) 0x31, (byte) 0xe6, (byte) 0x7e, (byte) 0xe8, (byte) 0xb9, (byte) 0xc5, (byte) 0xf2, (byte) 0xc7, (byte) 0x1d, (byte) 0x78, (byte) 0xf3, (byte) 0xef, (byte) 0x8d, 0x61, (byte) 0xf7, (byte) 0x3b, (byte) 0xcc, (byte) 0x17, (byte) 0xc3, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x23, (byte) 0x52, (byte) 0x4a, (byte) 0x8b, (byte) 0x9c, (byte) 0xb1, (byte) 0x75, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x66, (byte) 0xe6, (byte) 0xb3
        };

        // 2 1 3 -> 152
        // 4 : 02 8f 1a 9c
        // 128 : xxx
        // 20 : 5b ed 04 ed c3 cd 5f e6 a8 28 90 3b 42 58 15 cb 74 7d ee 85
        byte fply_3[] = {
            0x46, (byte) 0x50, (byte) 0x4c, (byte) 0x59, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x98, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x8f, 0x1a, (byte) 0x9c, (byte) 0x6e, (byte) 0x73, (byte) 0xd2, (byte) 0xfa, (byte) 0x62, (byte) 0xb2, (byte) 0xb2, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x6f, (byte) 0x52, (byte) 0x5f, (byte) 0xe5, (byte) 0x72, (byte) 0xa5, (byte) 0xac, (byte) 0x4d, (byte) 0x19, (byte) 0xb4, (byte) 0x7c, (byte) 0xd8, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x1e, (byte) 0xdb, (byte) 0xbc, (byte) 0x98, (byte) 0xae, (byte) 0x7e, (byte) 0x4b, (byte) 0xb4, (byte) 0xb7, 0x2a, (byte) 0x7b, (byte) 0x5e, (byte) 0x2b, (byte) 0x8a, (byte) 0xde, (byte) 0x94, (byte) 0x4b, (byte) 0x1d, (byte) 0x59, (byte) 0xdf, (byte) 0x46, (byte) 0x45, (byte) 0xa3, (byte) 0xeb, (byte) 0xe2, 0x6d, (byte) 0xa2, (byte) 0x83, (byte) 0xf5, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x53, (byte) 0x8f, (byte) 0x76, (byte) 0xe7, (byte) 0xd3, (byte) 0x68, (byte) 0x3c, (byte) 0xeb, (byte) 0x1f, (byte) 0x80, (byte) 0x0e, 0x68, (byte) 0x9e, (byte) 0x27, (byte) 0xfc, (byte) 0x47, (byte) 0xbe, (byte) 0x3d, (byte) 0x8f, (byte) 0x73, (byte) 0xaf, (byte) 0xa1, (byte) 0x64, (byte) 0x39, (byte) 0xf7, (byte) 0xa8, (byte) 0xf7, (byte) 0xc2, (byte) 0xc8, (byte) 0xb0, (byte) 0x20, (byte) 0x0c, (byte) 0x85, (byte) 0xd6, (byte) 0xae, (byte) 0xb7, (byte) 0xb2, (byte) 0xd4, (byte) 0x25, (byte) 0x96, (byte) 0x77, (byte) 0x91, (byte) 0xf8, (byte) 0x83, (byte) 0x68, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0xa1, (byte) 0xa9, (byte) 0x15, (byte) 0x4a, (byte) 0xa3, (byte) 0x37, (byte) 0x8c, (byte) 0xb7, (byte) 0xb9, (byte) 0x89, (byte) 0xbf, (byte) 0x86, (byte) 0x6e, (byte) 0xfb, (byte) 0x95, (byte) 0x41, (byte) 0xff, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x57, (byte) 0x61, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x73, (byte) 0xcc, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x7e, (byte) 0x4f, (byte) 0xc7, (byte) 0x96, (byte) 0xae, (byte) 0xba, (byte) 0x5b, (byte) 0xed, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0xed, (byte) 0xc3, (byte) 0xcd, (byte) 0x5f, (byte) 0xe6, (byte) 0xa8, (byte) 0x28, (byte) 0x90, (byte) 0x3b, (byte) 0x42, (byte) 0x58, 0x15, (byte) 0xcb, (byte) 0x74, (byte) 0x7d, (byte) 0xee, (byte) 0x85
        };

        // 2 1 4 -> 20 : 5b ed 04 ed c3 cd 5f e6 a8 28 90 3b 42 58 15 cb 74 7d ee 85
        byte fply_4[] = {
            0x46, (byte) 0x50, (byte) 0x4c, (byte) 0x59, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x14, (byte) 0x5b, (byte) 0xed, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0xed, (byte) 0xc3, (byte) 0xcd, (byte) 0x5f, (byte) 0xe6, (byte) 0xa8, (byte) 0x28, (byte) 0x90, (byte) 0x3b, (byte) 0x42, (byte) 0x58, (byte) 0x15, (byte) 0xcb, (byte) 0x74, 0x7d, (byte) 0xee, (byte) 0x85
        };

        ChannelBuffer content = req.getContent();

        int length = content.capacity();

        byte fply_header[] = new byte[12];
        content.getBytes(0, fply_header);
        length = fply_header.length;

        int rlocation = fply_header.length;
        int rlength = content.capacity() - fply_header.length;

        ChannelBuffer payload = content.copy(rlocation, rlength);

        if (fply_header[6] == 1) {

            int rloc = 12 + 2;
            int rl = 1;

            content.getBytes(13, fply_2, rloc, rl);
            replyOK(ctx, fply_2, req);

        } else if (fply_header[6] == 3) {

            int rloc = payload.capacity() - 20;
            int rl = 20;

            byte data[] = new byte[12];
            System.arraycopy(fply_4, 0, data, 0, data.length);

            ChannelBuffer sd = payload.copy(rloc, rl);
            byte[] subData = new byte[sd.capacity()];
            sd.getBytes(0, subData);

            byte[] rep = new byte[data.length + subData.length];
            System.arraycopy(data, 0, rep, 0, data.length);

            System.arraycopy(subData, 0, rep, data.length, subData.length);

            String s = new String(rep);
            Log.i("response", s);

            replyOK(ctx, rep, req);
        }
        return;
    } else if (method.toString().equals("POST") && req.getUri().equals("/auth-setup")) {

        ChannelBuffer content = req.getContent();

        byte[] rep = new byte[content.capacity()];
        content.getBytes(0, rep);

        replyOK(ctx, rep, req);
        return;

    } else if (RaopRtspMethods.ANNOUNCE.equals(method)) {
        announceReceived(ctx, req);
        return;
    }
    else if (RaopRtspMethods.SETUP.equals(method)) {...............
    }
}
```

And:

```
public synchronized void replyOK(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, byte[] data, final HttpRequest req) throws Exception {

    final HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpResponse(RtspVersions.RTSP_1_0, RtspResponseStatuses.OK);

    if (data.length > 0) {

        response.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
        response.addHeader("Content-Length", Integer.toString(data.length));
    }

    response.addHeader("Server", "AirTunes/104.29");
    response.addHeader("X-Apple-ET", req.getHeader("X-Apple-ET"));
    response.addHeader("CSeq", req.getHeader("CSeq"));

    response.setContent(ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer(data));

    ctx.getChannel().write(response);

}
```

Let me know if this solves the issue for you.